# mysql return null if such row exists otherwise return data

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Hi Is there any option in mysql query to return NULL is there is no such  row exists in database otherwise return the row data.  Here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT estimateResourceMthObj
       FROM EstimateResourceMth estimateResourceMthObj 
       WHERE estimateResourceMthObj.estimateResource.id IN 
            (
                    SELECT estimateResourceObj.id 
                    FROM EstimateResource estimateResourceObj
                    WHERE estimateResourceObj.estimateSub.id = 7 
            ) 
       AND estimateResourceMthObj.monthOrder >= 0 
       AND estimateResourceMthObj.monthOrder <  7;
```

I need to return the result of this query null if there is no such row exists otherwise i need to select that row. Is it possible to retrieve this in a single query?

Comment: so you are using hibernate, I imagine you are using query.list().  Is there a reason why you just can't check for an empty list and return null from your function?

Answer (score 0):

As a tricky solution you can add `UNION SELECT NULL LIMIT 0,1` to the end if you expect only one row, as you specified. So the result will always have one value - `NULL` if there are no matches in table and `estimateResourceMthObj` if there are.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT estimateResourceMthObj
       FROM EstimateResourceMth estimateResourceMthObj 
       WHERE estimateResourceMthObj.estimateResource.id IN 
            (
                    SELECT estimateResourceObj.id 
                    FROM EstimateResource estimateResourceObj
                    WHERE estimateResourceObj.estimateSub.id = 7 
            ) 
       AND estimateResourceMthObj.monthOrder >= 0 
       AND estimateResourceMthObj.monthOrder <  7
UNION
 SELECT NULL
LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: I think union is good option but but the query return error when i try the query `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL LIMIT 0,1:' at line 2`

Comment: in your comment the last char (in quotes) is colon - is that typo or you really added this to query? btw what mysql version do you use?

Comment: **no it is not in th query**. Original query is `SELECT *  FROM estimate_resource_mth estimateResourceMthObj WHERE estimateResourceMthObj.Estimate_resourceId IN( SELECT estimateResourceObj.id FROM estimate_resource estimateResourceObj WHERE estimateResourceObj.id=2) AND estimateResourceMthObj.month_order >= 0 
       AND estimateResourceMthObj.month_order <  7 UNION NULL LIMIT 0,1`;

Comment: you missed SELECT keyword: must be UNION SELECT NULL

Comment: I have chenged it now the error is `#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`.

Comment: Ah, I see. In your question you wrote that you need to select one certain column. Now you try to get them all (SELECT *), so you have to write as many NULLs as many fields are present in the result of first select. if SELECT * takes e.g. 4 columns, you must write UNION SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL. I know it's a bit tricky now, but I said it from the beginning :--)

Comment: The query works but i am again stuck on the result i got. It only return one NULL row. Iwas expecting it will retuen all the rows as a null value if month_order value is not there.Sorry.. Anyway thanks..